# Problem with xml dom document 

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'model.xml' );
$fields = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "field" );

$i = 0 ; 
foreach($fields as $field) 
{
    $name = $field->getAttribute('name') ; 
    $type = $field->getAttribute('type') ; 
    /* constraints */
    $con =  $field->getElementsByTagName('constraints') ;  
    foreach($con as $c) 
    {
        $min_length = $c->getElementsByTagName('min_length')->item(0)->nodeValue  ; 
        $max_length = $c->getElementsByTagName('max_length')->item(0)->nodeValue ; 
        if ($c->getElementsByTagName('required')->item(0))
        {
            $required = 1 ;  
        }
    }
    //check input types 
    if($type == 'text' || $type == 'password')
    {
        echo $field->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0)->nodeValue.'&nbsp; : ' ; 
        //create input tag
        echo '<input type="'.$type.'" name="'.$name.'" min_length="'.$min_length.'" max_length="'.$min_length.'"' ;
        //add required field to input 
        ($required == 1) ? print('class="required" /><span style="color:red">*</span><br />') : ('/><br />'); 

    }elseif($type == 'radio'){

        echo $field->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0)->nodeValue.'&nbsp; : <br /> ' ; 
        $items = $field->getElementsByTagName('item') ;
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $labels[] = $item->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0)->nodeValue  ; 
                $values[] = $item->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->nodeValue  ; 
            }


            for($i=0 ; $i<=(count($labels)-1);$i++)
            {
                //create inputs 
                echo $labels[$i].'&nbsp; : <input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$values[$i].'" ' ;
                ($required == 1 ) ? print('checked="checked" /><span style="color:red">*</span><br />') : ('/><br />');
            }
    }elseif($type == 'select'){

        echo $field->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0)->nodeValue.'&nbsp; : <br /> ' ; 
        $items = $field->getElementsByTagName('item') ;
            foreach($items as $item)
            {
                $labels[] = $item->getElementsByTagName('label')->item(0)->nodeValue  ; 
                $values[] = $item->getElementsByTagName('value')->item(0)->nodeValue  ; 
            }

            echo '<select name="'.$name.'">' ; 
            for($i=0 ; $i<=(count($labels)-1);$i++)
            {
                //create inputs 
                echo '<option value="'.$values[$i].'" >'.$labels[$i].'</option>' ; 
            }
            echo '</select>'; 
    }
```

here is my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<fields>
    <field name="first_name" type="text">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <constraints>
            <required/>
            <min_length>1</min_length>
            <max_length>255</max_length>
        </constraints>
     </field>
    <field name="password" type="password">
        <label>Password</label>
        <constraints>
            <required/>
            <min_length>6</min_length>
            <max_length>8</max_length>
        </constraints>
    </field>
    <field name="age" type="text">
        <label>Age</label>
        <constraints>
            <min>1</min>
            <max>99</max>
        </constraints>
     </field>
    <field name="gender" type="radio">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <item>
            <label>Male</label>
            <value>1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <label>Female</label>
            <value>2</value>
        </item>
        <constraints>
            <required/>
        </constraints>
    </field>
    <field name="language" type="select">
        <label>Language(s)</label>
        <item>
            <label>English</label>
            <value>1</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <label>French</label>
            <value>2</value>
        </item>
        <item>
            <label>Persian</label>
            <value>4</value>
        </item>
        <constraints/>
    </field>
</fields>
```

if you run this code you can see radio items repeat in select HTML view How do i avoid this happen .

Comment: Can you isolate the problem a bit more and describe what happens? I doubt many users are interested in making this run on their local environment first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not unsetting $labels & $values, so once the loop completes, it still remembers the values from before, add something like the following at the top of the foreach($fields... loop.

```
$labels = null;
$values = null;
```